# Keep different folders under the same repository

Tags: bash, git

I would like to keep my browser sessions (plain files) and notes (plain files) under the same github repository.

The porblem is that the two folders are located in different path and I have no idea how to keep them under the same github repo.

Comment: Symlinks? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [symbolic links](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/creating-soft-link-or-symbolic-link/). For instance, if you want to link /path/to/foldera and /path/to/folderb, you can initialize git in /path/to/foldera and link /path/to/folderb to /path/to/foldera using:

```
ln -s /path/to/folderb /path/to/foldera
```